# Executing a .jar which makes use of native libraries (Java , .dll)

Tags: java, dll, jar

I have 2 different projects in java and I need to do the following with them:
After a certain button from the *program A* is pressed, the *program B* is loaded and the *program A* is closed.
Even though both projects have classes and dlls in common, I really do not want to merge everything into one single project.

I have done some searching and I found out that one possible solution would be to load the *program B* from a .jar using the following example of code:

```
btnMyButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java.exe -jar \\url\\ProgramB.jar");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

I tried many variations of this (without the `".exe"`, for instance), and I made sure that the `ProgramB.jar` was in the same folder of its dlls, but nothing of this seemed to work.

So, I tried to open the `ProgramB.jar` directly (via Windows), and apparently everything was ok.

Later on, I tried to execute the `ProgramB.jar` via cmd (because I thought that the command `"java.exe -jar \\url\\ProgramB.jar"` could be executed on it).
Even though I have set the library path (`java -Djava.library.path=\\url\\ -jar \\url\\ProgramB.jar`), an UnsatisfiedLinkError was thrown every time(X.dll->cannot find dependent libraries).

**(Note: I won't be able to provide all the exception messages for a while because by the moment I do not have the program with me...)**

Anyway, I am not sure exactly what I am doing wrong, but apparently there aren't any problems with the dlls implementation, 
since I was able to execute the program at least once. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: sorry for edits. Now it's ok!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is java does not recognize the dll if is not in java.path

**So first solution:**

```
 put your dll in a java.path for example in windows C:\Windows\System32
```

**Second solution**

```
Set a new java variable which indicating the path where exist .dll file.
```

Also VMoption must be like:
-`Djava.library.path="path_to_dll"`

This is not correct -`Djava.library.path=path_to_dll\\dllname.dll`

Comment: I tried both of your advices and I keep having the same problem regarding the dependent libraries...